# CSS: wrap text <pre> tag break words issue

Tags: css, laravel, text, word-wrap

I use Laravel with CSS Bootstrap. I save the text into the field name (text data type). When I show it in `<pre>` tag wrap with below CSS, I got problem text are unwanted broken down into piece for every words that comes at the end of the `<pre>` as in this image.

> [image: See image]

And here is the CSS I used, which cause this problem:

```
.myclass pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `display: inline-block` to your `pre` tag for the word-wrap to work.

So your code becomes:

```
.myclass pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}
```